# How to find out a process name for an application, when desktop application uses a different name in the taskbar?

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop

Usually a desktop application uses a similar name in the taskbar, that it uses in the `ps` output.

For example, Evolution mail client can be started from a command-line as `evolution`.

But some applications use completely different naming, for example `vinagre` is `Remote Desktop Viewer` preinstalled on the Ubuntu with Gnome.

Question: How can I get the process name `vinagre`, so I can kill it in the process list, when I don't know what I am looking for and I know only that it's name is "Remote Desktop Viewer"? But in general?

Situation: I was using a "Remote Desktop Viewer" to connect to the RDP server, but it got into a weird situation, where I wasn't able to cancel any operation or close the application from the desktop, and I was not able to navigate into the "Help -> About", where is usually this information written. My only way how to kill the process was with `kill` command, but I was not able to find it in the process list. How can proceed in future in a general way?

Comment: The desktop names are set in the `.desktop` files (at least in gnome), and are set according to the locale. So it could be any name in any language (you can edit the desktop file to put the name you like for example). So, as far as I can see, the only solution left is to find the `.desktop` file and look the `Exec` line.